# Adding tab to another unlocked lightning APP

Tags: lightning-apps, scratch-org, unlocked-package

I am trying to assign a tab to the Lightning App, which is part of another unlocked package. However, I am unable to add any tab(standard object or custom objects) to Lightning App. I am getting the following error:

> We had trouble processing the request. We've reported the problem to Customer Support with error ID: -1471755171

I can use any object with another lightning apps. If anyone knows a workaround for the same, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the very same issue with the same error ID here, right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KS4NQAW) from Salesforce.

Copying workaround from the official site, which worked for me.

> **Workaround**
>
> The only reasonable workaround is to release the affected
>   entity from the unlocked package. On the org where the package was
>   installed, you can view components. On that page, there should be a
>   "Remove" action next to the component. That will disassociate the
>   component from the package and then should free it to be edited just
>   like any entity in the org.
>
> **Reference** -
>
> Q. How can I remove metadata from my package?
>
> https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html#remove-md